# Why keyboard go button not performing any actions in ionic 4 app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm creating ionic 4 angular app , and using some input fields and text area. when i click on input field and written some worlds then click on go button from keyboard that's go button not perform any action or not moving to next fields. i want when click on go button then it will jump to next input fields.

Comment: please guy's help me.

Comment: Have you got the inputs and textareas wrapped in a `<form>` tag?

Comment: No Sir , i'm using ion-grid ,ion-row ,ion-col .

Comment: I'm saying that I think that the `form` tag ties it together as a form, so the enter / go button goes to the next form field.